# Flame Simulation: Particle Template Setting: (Scenekit)

Tags: swift, scenekit, particle-system, particles

How would I begin to simulate a flame with Scenekit?

Is there an algorithmic preset or editor template I could use as a base from which to explore particle system (SCNParticleSystem) settings for flame like effects?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Xcode 6 includes a particle editor for SceneKit.
It also includes a "Fire" template (File > New > File... > [OSX or iOS] > SceneKit Particle System > Fire)

Comment: Xcode 11, Apple removed the ability to add new Scenekit Particle Files; therefore, the fire template isn't available now.